# Read from Firebase Realtime Database where reference = User UID

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a new user with authentication, and setting the User Key in the database as the User UID.

```
private fun writeNewUser(name: String, email: String?) {
        val user = User(name, email)
        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).setValue(user)
}
```

This works fine and produces the following result:
[image: Authentication + Write Database Result]

I'm now trying to login and read that user's information.

I'm trying to set the UID as the database reference (after having successfully logged in).
*My Login process is working.

I'm getting an error on MainActivity where I'm trying to display the data:

***Error***:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

***Line***:
key?.let { getValue(mAuth.uid) }

Here's my MainActivity code where I'm trying to read and display the data.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mUser: User
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        fun currentUserReference(): DatabaseReference =
            mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)

        currentUserReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            ValueListenerAdapter{
                mUser = it.asUser()!!
                tv_main_name.setText(mUser.name)
                tv_main_email.setText(mUser.email)
            }
        )

    }

    fun DataSnapshot.asUser(): User? =
        //error on this line ↓
        key?.let { getValue(mAuth.uid) }


}
```

**Edit 1**

Existing ValueListenerAdapter.kt

```
class ValueListenerAdapter(val handler: (DataSnapshot) -> Unit): ValueEventListener {

    private val TAG = "ValueListenerAdapter"

    override fun onDataChange(data: DataSnapshot) {
        handler(data)
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e("onCancelled", TAG, error.toException())
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mUser: User
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
             .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                        //Declare mUser as chosen DB User

                        tv_main_name.setText(mUser.name)
                        tv_main_email.setText(mUser.email)
                    }
                })
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

```
override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
     if (p0.hasChildren()) {
          //Declare mUser as chosen DB User
          tv_main_name.setText(mUser.name)
          tv_main_email.setText(mUser.email)
          }                        
     }
```

Comment: What's the error? Please add it to your question.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: key?.let { getValue(mAuth.uid) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                       //handle error
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (p0.hasChildren()) {
//If you have model for your user data object then do it like this.
                                                  val user = p0.getValue(YourModel::class.java)

                    }

                })
```

That's all you need to do to get current logged in user data from **users** node

Comment: I do have a ValueListener class, I have added it to my post. Should I adapt it to look like yours?

Comment: Yes please try like I did you will get the current logged in user data

Comment: If I do that, should I then get rid of the DataSnapshot function in MainActivity because it's no longer required?

Comment: Yes you can remove it.

Comment: Ok. trying now... fingers crossed.

Comment: Please share the result.if it helps

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what's going on and I have stripped out most of the old code. Please see my post Edit 2 for the new code. I just need to declare my variable mUser as the chosen database user (I think!). Am I close now?

Comment: Yes looks good now please add this condition too like i did else it may cause problem in some case       if (p0.hasChildren()) {}

Comment: Ok, please see Edit 3. Also, can you let me know how to declare mUser as the chosen DB User which I believe goes above my setText declarations.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps you so that it may helps others too.Thanks

Comment: Sure, I will accept it. But can you help me just finish it off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211365/discussion-between-black4guy-and-deku).

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mUser: User
    private lateinit var mAuth : FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
             .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {

                    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                        TODO("Not yet implemented")
                    }

                    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                        if (p0.hasChildren()) {
                            val user = p0.getValue(User::class.java)
                            tv_main_name.text = user?.name
                            tv_main_email.text = user!!.email
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
}
```